# How to select the last value when using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi i"m having a table of "invoices"

```
customer_number | Invoice_Number | Name | Address | Total_Amount
```

select i"m making `group by` customer_number
and sum the Total_amount of it's invoices.
I still want to show his name and address at the output.
dumping the Invoice_number.

However Address and even name of a customer my change, i want to make a columns of the latest `address` and `name` according to the last invoice_number of the specific customer.

How sould i do that ?
I"m usind ms sql

Comment: add Max(invoice_number) in your output

Comment: could you please provide some sample data and your expected output in table format?

Comment: Use a sub-select to perform 'group by' clause and then ordering the results of that query downward by your invoice_number

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT customer_number
      ,Name
      ,Address
      ,Total_Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT customer_number
          ,Name
          ,Address
          ,SUM(Total_Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_number) AS Total_Amount
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_number ORDER BY Invoice_Number DESC) AS row_id
    FROM [my_table] 
) DS
WHERE row_id = 1;
```

Using `OVER` clause we can calculate the sum for each row. It's like grouping but instead `group by` we are using `PARTITION BY` and instead one row per group, all rows are returned.

At the same time, we are using a ranking function to order the rows of each customer from the latest to the first by `invoce_number desc`.

And finally, we just need to get the rows we need.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for doing that based on your version of SQL Server. 
Below approach will work on any version, but might be slow if you have millions of rows. 
There are more decent ways if you are using earlier version.

```
select customer_number, TotamAmount = sum(Total_Amount)
, Name = (select top 1 Name from myTable where customer_number = t1.customer_number order by Invoice_Number desc)
, Address = (select top 1 Address from myTable where customer_number = t1.customer_number order by Invoice_Number desc)
from myTable t1
group by customer_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this  query

```
SELECT customer_number, 
       sumamount, 
       [name], 
       [address] 
FROM   (SELECT customer_number, 
               Sum (total_amount) 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY customer_number ) sumAmount, 
               [name], 
               [address], 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY customer_number 
                   ORDER BY [primarykey] )          AS [CustomerInvoiceId] 
        FROM   [tablename])X 
WHERE  [customerinvoiceid] = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

create table #temp
(

customer_number int

, Invoice_Number int

, Name varchar(50)

, Address varchar(50)

, Total_Amount int

)

insert into #temp values(1,1,'sam','india',100)

insert into #temp values(1,2,'sam k','USA',200)

insert into #temp values(2,3,'sandy','Africa',100)

insert into #temp values(2,4,'sandy sharma','india',200)

select t1.customer_number,t1.Invoice_Number,name,Address,sum(Total_Amount) total

from #temp t1

inner join

(

select max(Invoice_Number) as Invoice_Number,customer_number from #temp

group by customer_number

) t2 on t1.Invoice_Number=t2.Invoice_Number

and t1.customer_number=t2.customer_number

group by t1.customer_number,t1.Invoice_Number,name,Address

Comment: you cant have the same invoice number twice, 
and the sum amount does not sum here, it gives the last invoice line which is 200, and it has to be 300. moreover if you change the invoice number of one of the customers to 3 then you get only one line which is the last invoice number on the table.